# R Is there a way to do thresholding in linear regression?

Tags: r, linear-regression, threshold

I'm trying to do a linear regression but I'm only looking to use variables with positive coefficients (I think this is called hard-thresholding, but I'm not certain).

for example:

```
> summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = value ~ ., data = intCollect1[, -c(1, 3)])

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-15.6518  -0.2089  -0.0227   0.2035  15.2235 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     0.099763   0.024360   4.095 4.22e-05 ***
modelNum3802    0.208867   0.008260  25.285  < 2e-16 ***
modelNum8000   -0.086258   0.013104  -6.582 4.65e-11 ***
modelNum8001   -0.058225   0.010741  -5.421 5.95e-08 ***
modelNum8002   -0.001813   0.012087  -0.150 0.880776    
modelNum8003   -0.083646   0.011015  -7.594 3.13e-14 ***
modelNum8004    0.002521   0.010729   0.235 0.814254    
modelNum8005    0.301286   0.011314  26.630  < 2e-16 ***
```

In the above regression, I would only want to use models 3802, 8004 and 8005.  Is there a way to do this without copying and pasting each variable name?

Comment: You can check `?coef`.
But if you remove variables with a negative coefficient
and recompute the regression, 
the sign of the remaining coefficients can change.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `lm`, you can formulate your problem in terms of a Quadratic Programming:

Minimize the sum of the squared replication errors subject to the constraint that your linear coefficients are all positive.

Such problems can be solved using `lsei` from the `limSolve` package. Looking at your example, it would look a lot like this:

```
x.variables <- c("modelNum3802", "modelNum8000", ...)
num.var <- length(x.variables)

lsei(A = intCollect1[, x.variables],
     B = intCollect1$value,
     G = diag(num.var),
     H = rep(0, num.var))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the `nnls` (non-negative least square) package to be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reformulate your linear regression model in the following way:
label ~ sum(exp(\alpha_i) f_i)

the optimization target will be
sum_j (label_j - sum_i(exp(\alpha_i) f_i))^2

This has no closed form solution but can be solved efficiently since it's convex in the \alpha_i's.

Once you compute the \alpha_i's, you can recast them as the regressors of a usual linear model by exponentiating them.